# How can we separated the path into $4$ part?

Tags: calculus

find the of work done by the force$ f(x,y) = (x^2-y^2) i + 2xy j$  in moving a particles ( in a counter clockwise direction) once around a square bounded by the corrdinate  axes  and the line $ x=a$  and $y=a$ , $a >0$

My attempt : The given force field is $F(x,y) = (x^2-y^2, 2xy)$

from formula Workdone $= \int_{0}^{a} F( \alpha(t)) \alpha'(t) dt$

Answer : Given total work done $=\frac{-1}{2}$

I know How to derived the answer .

But my  confusion is that  How can we separated the path  into $4$ part ?

My thinking : The given path are  seperated into $4$ part

$\alpha_1(t)=(0, at) $ for  all $ t \in [0,a]$

$\alpha_2(t)=( 0,0) $ for  all $ t \in [0,a]$

$\alpha_3(t)=( at,0) $ for  all $  t \in [0,a]$

$\alpha_4(t)=( at,at) $ for  all $ t \in [0,a]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path $\alpha_1$ should be the bottom edge of the square $Q$, from left to right. This amounts to
$$\alpha_1(t)=(at,0)\qquad(0\leq t\leq 1)\ .$$
Then the right vertical edge, upwards:
$$\alpha_2(t)=(a, at)\qquad(0\leq t\leq1)\ .$$
Now the upper edge, leftwards:
$$\alpha_3(t)=(a-at,a)\qquad(0\leq t\leq1)\ ,$$
and finally the left vertical edge, downwards:
$$\alpha_4(t)=(0,a-at)\qquad(0\leq t\leq1)\ .$$
The full work done is then given by
$$W=\sum_{i=1}^4\int_{\alpha_i}{\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r}=\sum_{i=1}^4\int_0^1{\bf F}\bigl(\alpha_i(t)\bigr)\cdot \alpha_i'(t)\>dt\ .$$
Note that you can simplify matters a lot by using Green's theorem:
$$W=\int_Q{\rm curl}({\bf F})\>dA\ .$$